# traversing arraylist using EL using foreach

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, foreach, el

I have a class `language` having features `ID` and `Name`.
I have another class `Language_List` that has `ArrayList<language> lang` as a member variable.

In my JSP page I want to access the Name variable of `ArrayList<language> lang` using EL and For each Loop.

```
<c:forEach var="language" items="${languages.lang}">
  ${language}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

However, it doesn't show ant result and intellisense doesn't work too. Anyone who can help me with this
PS: languages is a Bean variable contain list of languages from DB
I tried this and got this

```
 <b>${languages.lang}</b>
HTML
```

**[sakila.language@f1541c, sakila.language@63c8fabf, sakila.language@1fc644c7, sakila.language@11cd751d, sakila.language@47c3cc0c, sakila.language@7894ca3, sakila.language@47066532, sakila.language@74ddda0b, sakila.language@1116441e, sakila.language@4cd21655, sakila.language@74b84dd9, sakila.language@6fff1d6c, sakila.language@55e4d6e5, sakila.language@22d88071, sakila.language@33d88c96, sakila.language@4df5e671, sakila.language@4aec2cb3, sakila.language@576ac232, sakila.language@76a6dbd7, sakila.language@44ab3d1c, sakila.language@46391c7c, sakila.language@4f7d34e8, sakila.language@251c941d, sakila.language@77400ef3]**

Comment: In your sample, `language` is a variable, not a class. Why not making the base class implement `Iterable` and provide a correct `.toString()` implementation for elements?

Comment: @fge what should I do in the body of .tostring(),You want to say that you can't access an Arraylist using EL?

Comment: I don't say you cannot access it, I just say that if the array is the only iterable thing in your class, you may as well make the class implement iterable of the elements in the array. As to .toString(), it depends on the information you want to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

The EL doesn't access fields of your objects. It accesses bean properties of your objects. This means that `${languages.lang}` is translated to a call to `languages.getLang()`.

If you don't have such a getter, you'll get an exception though. If it just doesn't display anything, it's probably because `languages` is null, or because its `lang` list is null or empty. To confirm or infirm those guesses, we need to see the code where you create and populate the bean and its list of languages, and where you store it somewhere to make it accessible from the JSP.

Another possibility is that you forgot to declare the core taglib at the beginning of the JSP. To confirm or infirm that, paste the code of the JSP, and the HTML code generated by the JSP (using *View page source* in the browser)

Comment: i have made an Edit, and the lang variable is not null as I did the debugging.If I use scriplets <% %> I can traverse easily..

Comment: So, it's very far from printing nothing. If you want it to display something meaningful, then display internal properties of each object, or override the `toString()` method in the Language class. (Please rename language to Language. Classes always start with an upper-case letter by convention in Java).